# Pulseaudio all volumes set to 100%

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio, volume-control

It happens when flat volumes = no.
When pulseaudio daemon is starting, it set all volumes to 0dB. On logon screen my speakers sounds like "BOOM!" It is not as annoying to change them every time as changing mic, monitor etc volumes as well.
Also i can't use enabled flat volumes because i want independent global volume, if you know what i mean.

Possibly workaround: i made simple script that using commands "set-source-volume" and "set-sink-volume". Would be great if someone tell me the nice place for autostart these commands when daemon starts.

**UPDATE:** Can i add this script to /etc/init.d/pulseaudio file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your `set-source-volume` and `set-sink-volume` commands directly to the pulse audio startup script located at `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. Add your commands to the end of that file.

(Or if you are using pulse in system-wide mode then use the `/etc/pulse/system.pa` file, but this is not the default.)

Comment: I tried both of these options. Neither worked for me. :( Any other suggestions?